# Modifying Spring MVC app to be accesseb by remoting from Eclipse RCP app

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, eclipse-rcp, remoting

I would like to ask what would be the best wa to modify a Spring MVC to be accessed via remoting from Eclipse RCP application? What approach would you choose and why?

And is there any tutorial regarding Eclipse RCP remoting on the web?

Any advices and recommendations are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My approach would be to have the Spring MVC app split in layers:

- the presentation layer is where Spring MVC is used. It contains the presentation logic and calls the service layer
- the service layer is where the business logic is. It calls the data access layer
- the data access layer is where the persistence logic is.

I would thus have to make some or all of the services of the service layer remotely accessible (using Spring HttpInvoker, web services or whatever), and potentially add some more dedicated to the specifics of the RCP app.

Comment: Yes, the app uses three layers design, and I'm expectinf Eclipse not to interact with MVC layer at all, what interests me the most is Eclipse side, and how to handle remote calls there

Comment: Spring HTTPInvoker is easy to set up and use.